# Bootstrap dropdown toggle menu istead of clicking arrow

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<ul style="padding:0px;" class="breadcrumb">                    
                    <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" style="color:#fff;"> settings</a>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a class="drpdwna" href="/one"><strong>One</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="drpdwna" href="/two"><strong>Two</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="drpdwna" href="/three"><strong>Three</strong></a>
            </li>           
                        </ul>
            </div>
            </ul>
```

it works onclick arrow , I am attempting to create a drop down toggle menu which activates on click root a i mean "settings".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
$(".btn-success").bind("click", function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: yeah nice , but i have used more than 3 dropdown in same page , if i click all dropdown will opening

Comment: I don't know if i understand you right, but if you want to open multiple dropdowns you can just add them in the function.
Like
    `$(".dropdown1").toggle();
    $(".dropdown2").toggle();`